# leaflet map is not showing using requirejs

Tags: typescript, leaflet, requirejs, bower, typescript-typings

I have:

inside **bower.json**:

```
"leaflet": "https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.git#^1.7.1"
```

inside **typings.json**:

```
"leaflet": "registry:dt/leaflet#1.0.0+20170324151803"
```

in **less** file:

```
#mapid { height: 180px; }
```

in **html** file:

```
<div id="mapid"></div>
```

and in the **ts code** I have:

```
requirejs.config({
   map: {
      '*' : {
          ...
          "leaflet": "../lib/leaflet/dist/leaflet"
      }  
   }


import leaflet = require("leaflet");

let map = leaflet.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
```

==>
**But the map does not load/show at all

All I get is this:**

[image]

Does anybody have any idea?

Maybe require is not related to the problem ?
Maybe it is the versions I'm using ?

Comment: Missing Leaflet CSS file.

Comment: thanks - that's exactly what was missing!